# Laravel Sum Eloquent sum of multiple multiplications from two different tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, sum

Currently, in my Laravel project controller, I am using one query

**QUERY 1**

```
public function cartreview(Request $request,$sp_id, $service_id,$cart_id)
    {
    $total = DB::table('pricings')
    ->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.shirt*carts.quantity_shirt ) AS total'))                      
    ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)
    ->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)
    ->first();
    }
```

In above query, I am using two database tables as **pricings** and **carts**
where I am calculating total bill price of shirt item by getting a **price from pricing** table and **quantity from carts** table.

Now I also want to add another item with a shirt like a pant, tie, etc. 
How do I pass more multiplication to the sum?

Please help me with the syntax. Can I do something like this

**QUERY 2**

```
    $total = DB::table('pricings')
        ->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.shirt*carts.quantity_shirt ,
                             pricings.pant*carts.quantity_pant , 
                             pricings.tie*carts.quantity_tie) AS total'))                      
        ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)
        ->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)
        ->first();
```

OR even if I calculate total separately for each item How do I add it?

```
$total_shirt = DB::table('pricings')
    ->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.shirt*carts.quantity_shirt ) AS total_shirt'))                      
    ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)
    ->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)
    ->first();

   $total_pant = DB::table('pricings')
    ->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.pant*carts.quantity_pant ) AS total_pant'))                      
    ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)
    ->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)
    ->first();

   $total_tie = DB::table('pricings')
    ->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.tie*carts.quantity_tie ) AS total_tie'))                      
    ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)
    ->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)
    ->first();
```

$total = $total_shirt + $total_pant + $total_tie; ?

To display value in view.blade.php I use something like {{$total->total}}

Thanks in advance.

TRIED :

```
$waftotal = DB::table('pricings')->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
                  ->select(DB::raw('sum(
                                        pricings.Regular_Laundry*carts.q_Regular_Laundry,
                                        pricings.Bedding_Mattress_Duvet_Cover*carts.q_Bedding_Mattress_Duvet_Cover,
                                        pricings.Bedding_Comforter_laundry*carts.q_Bedding_Comforter_laundry,
                                        pricings.Bedding_Blanket_Throw*carts.q_Bedding_Blanket_Throw,
                                        pricings.Bedding_Pillow_laundry*carts.q_Bedding_Pillow_laundry,
                                        pricings.Bath_Mat_laundry*carts.q_Bath_Mat_laundry,
                                        pricings.Every_Hang_Dry_Item*carts.q_Every_Hang_Dry_Item
                                        ) AS waftotal'))
                  ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)->first();
```

but it gives me error as

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' pricings.Bedding_Mattress_Duvet_Cover*c' at line 1 (SQL: select sum(pricings.Regular_Laundry*carts.q_Regular_Laundry, pricings.Bedding_Mattress_Duvet_Cover*carts.q_Bedding_Mattress_Duvet_Cover, pricings.Bedding_Comforter_laundry*carts.q_Bedding_Comforter_laundry, pricings.Bedding_Blanket_Throw*carts.q_Bedding_Blanket_Throw, pricings.Bedding_Pillow_laundry*carts.q_Bedding_Pillow_laundry, pricings.Bath_Mat_laundry*carts.q_Bath_Mat_laundry, pricings.Every_Hang_Dry_Item*carts.q_Every_Hang_Dry_Item ) AS waftotal from `pricings` inner join `carts` on `carts`.`sp_id` = `pricings`.`sp_id` where `pricings`.`sp_id` = 1 and `carts`.`id` = 23 limit 1)

Even if I write seperate queries

```
$waf1 = DB::table('pricings')->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
                  ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.Regular_Laundry*carts.q_Regular_Laundry) AS waf1'))
                  ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)->first();



                    $waf2 = DB::table('pricings')->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
                  ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.Bedding_Mattress_Duvet_Cover*carts.q_Bedding_Mattress_Duvet_Cover) AS waf2'))
                  ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)->first();



                    $waf3 = DB::table('pricings')->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
                  ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.Bedding_Comforter_laundry*carts.q_Bedding_Comforter_laundry) AS waf3'))
                  ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)->first();


                    $waf4 = DB::table('pricings')->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
                  ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.Bedding_Blanket_Throw*carts.q_Bedding_Blanket_Throw) AS waf4'))
                  ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)->first();

                    $waf5 = DB::table('pricings')->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
                  ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.Bedding_Pillow_laundry*carts.q_Bedding_Pillow_laundry) AS waf5'))
                  ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)->first();

                    $waf6 = DB::table('pricings')->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
                  ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.Bath_Mat_laundry*carts.q_Bath_Mat_laundry) AS waf6'))
                  ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)->first();

                    $waf7 = DB::table('pricings')->join('carts', 'carts.sp_id', '=', 'pricings.sp_id')
                  ->select(DB::raw('sum(pricings.Every_Hang_Dry_Item*carts.q_Every_Hang_Dry_Item) AS waf7'))
                  ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)->where('carts.id', '=' , $cart_id)->first();

$waftotal = $waf1->waf1 + $waf2->waf2 + $waf3->waf3 + $waf4->waf4 + $waf5->waf5 + $waf6->waf6 + $waf7->waf7 ;
```

In view.blade.php {{$waftotal}} or {{$waftotal->waftotal}} gives me eerror as Trying to get property of non-object .

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Your combined query should work fine.

Comment: Yeah, what's wrong with your first query?

Comment: can you `var_dump($waf1)` to see what it returns?

Comment: also you should really write Models and methods on them to return that kind of stuff, it'd be way cleaner

Comment: I suggest you read the Laravel doco and reorganise your code using Models and the ORM, this is very messy/experimental

Comment: I want something like query 2 from a question.  Calculating total of multiple items for billing.

Comment: waftotal returns exact calculated value I want . I need to know how do I access/display it in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first()` will return an object, so you need to add the properties of each object:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Instead of `$total = $total_shirt + $total_pant + $total_tie`;

It would be `$total = $total_shirt->total_shirt + $total_pant->total_pant + $total_tie->total_tie;` since you have assigned the sum to each object to a property named after the object.

But your first combined query should work fine. What error do you get?

Comment: I have added my final query in question and the error I got.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$maintotal = DB::table('carts')
           ->join('products', 'carts.productid', '=', 'products.id')
           ->select(DB::raw('sum(products.price*carts.quantity) AS maintotal3'))
           ->where('carts.userid', '=', $useri)->get();
```

```
  @foreach($maintotal as $t)
     {{$t->maintotal3}}
  @endforeach
```